# Inserting Middleware(insights) with Instantsearch react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, instantsearch.js

So, we have a functional search with Algolia/Instantsearch/React/Nextjs. But the Insights middleware is currently not setup.

Below is a trimmed version of the implementation, we use custom widgets to have more fine control over the display of results.

We use the hooks implementation for the custom widgets like so

```
const { hits, sendEvent, ... } = useInfiniteHits(props)
```

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite'
import { InstantSearch, InstantSearchSSRProvider } from 'react-instantsearch-hooks-web'
import SearchBox from '@components/swatches/algolia/SearchBox'
import Hits from '@components/swatches/algolia/Hits'
import RefinementList from '@components/swatches/algolia/RefinementList'
import CurrentRefinements from '@components/swatches/algolia/CurrentRefinements'
import { getServerState } from 'react-instantsearch-hooks-server'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import { history } from 'instantsearch.js/es/lib/routers/index.js'
import styles from '@styles/page.module.scss'



const Page = ({ serverState, url }) => {

  const searchClient = algoliasearch(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_INDEX_ID,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY
  )
  return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <InstantSearchSSRProvider {...serverState}>
              <InstantSearch
                searchClient={searchClient}
                indexName={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_INDEX}
                routing={{
                  router: history({
                    getLocation: () =>
                      typeof window === 'undefined' ? new URL(url) : window.location,
                  }),
                }}
              >

                <Container fluid="lg">
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <SearchBox />
                  </div>
                  <CurrentRefinements />
                  <Hits />
                </Container>
              </InstantSearch>
            </InstantSearchSSRProvider>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Page

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res, resolvedUrl}) {

  const protocol = req.headers.referer?.split('://')[0] || 'https';
  const url = `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`;
  const serverState = await getServerState(<Page url={url} />);

  return {
    props: {
      serverState,
      url,
    },
  }
}
```

So my question is, where do we hook up the insights middleware for this specific implementation?

Reading the docs, (https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/react-hooks/) I'm not really 100% sure where to start. I can't find anywhere in the instantsearch react docs where it references anyway to configure that sort of thing.

Am I better of just firing events at the API directly instead of with InstantSearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trick is finding the `InstantSearch` instance using `useInstantSearch`:

```
const instantSearch = useInstantSearch();
instantSearch.use(middleware)
```

The [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/middleware/js/) should tell you what to do from there.